# Yii2 htaccess route

Tags: php, .htaccess, yii2

This is how my .htaccess looks like:

```
Options -Indexes

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c> 
  RewriteEngine on

  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^public
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ frontend/web/$1 [L] 
</IfModule>

# Deny accessing below extensions
<Files ~ "(.json|.lock|.git)">
Order allow,deny
Deny from all
</Files>

# Deny accessing dot files
RewriteRule (^\.|/\.) - [F]
```

My frontend/config/main.php:

```
 'urlManager' => [
            'baseUrl' => '/myweb/',
            'enablePrettyUrl' => false,
            'showScriptName' => true,
            'rules' => []
],
```

And that's fine. Also in frontend/config/main-local.php I have:

```
'baseUrl' => '/myweb.com/'.
```

Of course, in request.

Anyway, there are two problems:

1. How to make access for backend. Lets say I want make it as: `myweb.com/admin/`.
2. Why `Url::to([("controller/action")];` makes this link: `http://localhost/myweb.com/web/frontend/?r=controller/action`. It should look like `localhost/myweb.com/?r=controller/action`.

For now, I don't want to make pretty URLs.

Best regards.

Answer (score 1):

You could add another UrlManager component :

```
'components' => [
    'urlManager' => [
        // here is your normal frontend url manager config
        'scriptUrl' => '/myweb.com/index.php', // instead of baseUrl
    ],
    'urlManagerBackend ' => [
        // here is your backend URL manager config
    ],

],
```

And to make a link :

```
echo Yii::$app->urlManagerBackend->createUrl('admin');
```

As explained [here](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-tutorial-advanced-app.html#creating-links-from-backend-to-frontend), and discussed [here](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/issues/1578).

And since you are not using pretty urls, you should set `scriptUrl` instead of `baseUrl` (take a look here https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/blob/2.0.2/framework/web/UrlManager.php#L309)

Comment: Thanks. Frontend works. But backend doesn't. It returns 404 error: The requested url /myweb.com/frontend/index.php was not found on this server.

Comment: You should handle this in .htaccess

Comment: Thank you for your answers. Everything except pretty URLs is fine. What should I do for pretty URLs? Is there something I could change. Currently, its just enabled.